# Помогите получить id3 tag на js

Tags: javascript, html, аудио, mp3

На сайт необходимо сделать загрузку mp3 файлов, они автоматически должны записываться в базу по id3 тегам, желательно получать их в браузере пользователя, а после уже ajax ом передавать буду... Надо получить всего 3 параметра (картинку из mp3, название, автора) Я проверил много проектов на гитхабе,  несколько было залито на `jsfiddle` но они тоже не особо хотели работать...

Comment: Честно говоря, не знал, что в МП3 можно зашить картинку. Где об этом можно почитать информацию?

Comment: На мобильном телефоне замечали в музыке иногда появляются фоновые картинки с авторами и рисунками на тематику музыки(не всегда, но бывает) их зашивают как обложку ф вайл

Comment: https://kb-ru.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10799/~/Добавление-обложки-альбома-к-песне%2C-используя-windows-media-player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно получить теги именно на клиенте, то [JavaScript-ID3-Reader](https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader) Вам в помощь, а на PHP можно без библиотек с помощью функции [id3_get_tag](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.id3-get-tag.php).

Comment: на js скачал, запустил пример...вставил  файл... нифига не делает

Comment: Я только что тоже скачал, (правда, впервые) у меня делает, но русские буквы отображаются в неправильной кодировке. (Кажется, западноевропейская - Îëåã Îïàíàñåíêî что-то на подобие.) Что я только не пробовал, так и не удалось разобраться с кодировкой. Попробуйте для рачала мп3-файл, в котором теги латинскими буквами.